# The server cant resolve host names

Tags: dns, iptables

Please help with the following problem.

Server is running under Ubuntu 14.04 server 32x.
IP tables:

```
INPUT DROP [0:0]  :FORWARD DROP [0:0]  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0] 

-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 


-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 548 -j ACCEPT 

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT 

-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 

-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT 

-A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 

-A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED -j ACCEPT 

-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 

-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED -j ACCEPT 

-A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 548 -j ACCEPT
```

When I try to ping hosts by their name from the server console, I get "unknown hosts".
Ping using IP address work.

What may I change in my iptables?

Comment: flush the iptable rules (iptables -F)  and try again. If dns lookup resolved, then there is something wrong with the rules.

Comment: Without the rules - all is ok.
But what is wrong with rules?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved by adding those strings:

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1024:65535 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1024:65535 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Adding those string where?